# How to preload in gorm many to many with the condition in join table

Tags: go, go-gorm

It's me again...
Now the big issues for me but I hard to think about it
Now I can preload in gorm. But when using preload for many to many table with the join table... I have some issues that I dont know
I have 3 table

```
type Product struct{
Categories []Category `gorm:"many2many:Product_Category"`
}
type Category struct{}
type Product_Category struct {}
```

some kind like that. I now can using Preload("Categories").Find(&products)
But the problem here is how can I filter the product with category?
**Mean I need to add the condition in the join table Product_Category when preload the category? Are there any solutions?**

**And beside that, I wonder how to add/update the product with categories into 2 table Product and Product_Category?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
type Product struct{
Product
Categories []Category `gorm:"many2many:product_category;foreignKey:ID;joinForeignKey:ProductID;References:ID;joinReferences:CategoryID"`
}
type Category struct{}
type Product_Category struct {}
```

This says

- Create a many 2 many relationship with 1 foreign key being id of one model with reference as "product_id" and similar for other.
- then all you need to do is simply preload Categories

Comment: hey. Thanks for your help. But I almost solved this problem! Have a good day

Comment: @Dũng - When something like that happen you should post an answer to your own question or at least update the question so others can benefit from this post

Comment: sorry about that. I forgot to say, but it kinda like the answer of @Rohan kumar above! Thanks for your feedback! I will remember next time